# MongoDB collections design

Tags: mongodb

I've got such four tables:
[image]

Point is that users that joined in particular group have access to a survey for time interval from date to date. How should i organize collection structure of such db in mongodb?

For survey and questions this will be a simple colection of surveys with an array of questions. But for this behavior with start/end of survey it is not clear for me how to store this data.

Comment: It's not 100% clear for me... Do you mean that surveys have start and end date or that a registration is valid only in a predefined time span

Comment: @Clijsters, registration is valid only in a predefined time span.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like.

Groups

```
{
 _id : "group1",
 "members" : [{"name":"A"...},{"name":"B"...}],
 "surveys" : [{"surveyId":"survey1", "startDate": ISODate(),"endDate":ISODate()},{"surveyId":"survey2", "startDate": ISODate(),"endDate":ISODate()}]
}
```

Surveys

```
{
 _id : "survey1",
 questions : [{"text":"Atheist??"...},{....}]
}
```

Honestly, it depends on what pattern you want to use, I mean you can embed groups inside survey also with registration details.